# How implement elementIdEnabled() in nightwatch

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I was trying to see if element enabled on the page before clicking on that. I want to create command that will check if element is enabled or not before clicking on it. I was going over API of nightwatch and still not sure how this commands works. I was trying following:

```
browserObj.elementIdEnabled(Cssselector, function (res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

But I think I should pass something else and not css selector into elementIdEnabled function. Ideally I want to chain 3 commands before clicking on element:

```
browserObj.perform(function () {
this.waitForElementPresent(cssSelector, timeout, function () {
this.waitForElementVisible(cssSelector, timeout, function () {
  this.api.elementIdEnabled(cssSelector, function (res) {
    browserObj.click(cssSelector, function (clickStatus) {
      this.assert.equal(clickStatus.status, 0 );
    });
  })
})
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.command = function (selector) {
  this.waitForElementVisible(selector).click(selector);
  return this;
};
```

By beatfactor from 
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/705